# WPF InputHitTest doesn't detect label on click

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a canvas and line & label pairs on it. They have same tags. When i click lines, it detects it and deletes both line and label with the same tag. But when i click labels, it does not.

Here is my detection code:

```
private void MainCanvas_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var mousePosition = Mouse.GetPosition(mainCanvas);

    Line c1 = mainCanvas.InputHitTest(mousePosition) as Line;

    if (c1 != null && c1.Tag != null && c1.Tag.ToString().StartsWith("dist"))
    {
        string tag = c1.Tag.ToString();
        var list = mainCanvas.Children
                             .Cast<FrameworkElement>()
                             .Where(a => a.Tag != null && a.Tag.Equals(tag))
                             .ToList();

        foreach(var i in list)
        {
            mainCanvas.Children.Remove(i);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Label c2 = mainCanvas.InputHitTest(mousePosition) as Label;

        if (c2 != null && c2.Tag != null && c2.Tag.ToString().StartsWith("dist"))
        {
            string tag = c2.Tag.ToString();
            var list = mainCanvas.Children
                                 .Cast<FrameworkElement>()
                                 .Where(a => a.Tag != null && a.Tag.Equals(tag))
                                 .ToList();

            foreach (var i in list)
            {
                mainCanvas.Children.Remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `mainCanvas.InputHitTest(mousePosition) as Label`  returns null because the hit element is not a Label, but the TextBlock in its ContentTemplate. Better don't use Labels, but TextBlocks instead.

Comment: You may also not need to do any hit testing at all. Check the MouseButtonEventArgs' Source and OriginalSource properties.

Comment: @Clemens, it works like a charm! Thank you. Will try your second suggest too. Appreciated :)